# iOS navigation bar item image size

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I want to customize my `NavigationBar` button and using my own images.

The question is what the size should be?

I found that the button size should be 40*40, so the image should be 80*80 for retina?

Answer (score 95):

These are the sizes that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/) recommends for custom icons now.

[image]

- @2: 50 x 50
- @3: 75 x 75

Create two images of the above pixel sizes and then add them to a new image set in your Assets.xcassets file. (Apparently the @1 size is no longer needed.)

[image]

Alternatively, you could use a universal vector image (pdf) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818845/how-do-vector-images-work-in-xcode-6-i-e-pdf-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149785/xcode-6-allows-vector-image-assets-any-idea-how-to-use-them)). This has been my preference recently.

**Related answer**

- [iOS how to set app icon and launch images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170520/ios-how-to-set-app-icon-and-launch-images/32136202#32136202)

Answer (score 25):

Apple updated their [Human Interface Guidelines Docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/). Now the recommended sizes for creating custom icons for **Navigation Bar** and **Toolbar**

- **@2x** - `48px × 48px` (24pt × 24pt @2x)
- **@3x** - `72px × 72px` (24pt × 24pt @3x)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The typical standard sizes (non-Retina) are 22px by 22px, while the 2x (or Retina) sizes are 44px by 44px.

Answer (score 5):

Apple docs were updated and now the recommended size is 25pt x 25pt.

Please refer to documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/navigation-and-search/navigation-bars).

Answer (score 5):

You should prepare 3 images icons for each tab bar item (1x, 2x and 3x).

First create the 3x at 75w 75h pixels (maximum: 144 x 96) and save it as iconTab0@3x.png.

Then resize it to 50w 50h pixels (maximum: 96 x 64) and save it as iconTab0@2x.png.

Finally resize it to 25w 25h pixels (maximum: 48 x 32) and save it as iconTab0.png.

Now all you need is to select those 3 images at your finder and drag them to your image assets.

human interface guidelines

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are the current sizes:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

"Toolbar and navigation bar - between 24x24 (@1x) and 28x28 (@1x)".

Comment: This link is no more reachable :[

Comment: Link should be up to date again