# UINavigationBar button clipped

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm testing custom button for embedded navigation bar, but when passing to a second VC buttons (or when I go back from second to first) seem to have a sort of "clipping" on top and bottom side I cannot avoid. I have a button where I have a background image with a circle, and arrows as image.

I tested even a custom button, but something is not working

an image of my issue

[image]

in my first VC:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //in SecondVC the image used as background seems a bit oval, or maybe "cutted" top and bottom sides
        addCustomUiButton()
        //this seems the best, but in SecondVC is cutted even more
        addBarButtonItem()

        //        multipleButtonOnTheSameSide()

        setImageForNavigation()
        customizeNavigationBar()
    }

    @IBAction func nextControllerButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNext", sender: nil)
    }

}


extension UIViewController {


    func addBarButtonItem() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "vectorSmartObject")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, landscapeImagePhone: nil, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(testAction))
        barButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "backgroundGreenCyrcle"), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        barButton.tintColor = .orange
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    }

    func addCustomUiButton()  {
        let myButton = CustomSimpleUiButton()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    func multipleButtonOnTheSameSide() {

        let button1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button1.setImage(UIImage (named: "modifyIcon"), for: .normal)
        button1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "backgroundGreenCyrcle"), for: .normal)
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
        //        button1.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)

        let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button2.setImage(UIImage (named: "vectorSmartObject"), for: .normal)
        button2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "backgroundGreenCyrcle"), for: .normal)
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)
        button2.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButtonItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button2)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem, barButtonItem2]

    }


    func customizeNavigationBar() {
        //        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear//.purple
        //        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .clear//.white

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }


    func setImageForNavigation() {
        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }

    @objc func testAction() {
        print("ok", Date())
    }


}
```

in my second VC

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setImageForNavigation()

        addBarButtonItem() //left, cutted a lot
        addCustomUiButton() //right, a bit cutted

//        multipleButtonOnTheSameSide() //a bit cutted
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
//        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }


}
```

my custom button

```
class CustomSimpleUiButton: UIButton {


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setImage(UIImage (named: "modifyIcon"), for: .normal)
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "backgroundGreenCyrcle"), for: .normal)
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 35.0, height: 35.0)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }


}
```

Comment: You might want to consider decreasing width and height of the button, also do introduce cornerRadius even though your background image seems to be circular. Moreover many times the sizes of images, if being bigger than what's required, can be problematic in navigation items.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232315/8541799

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it in addBarButtonItem ? seems cannot manipulate "layer" for UIBarButtonItem