# Padding for rightbar button item?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I can add some padding to my rightbarbuttonitem(eye icon) with the following codes but the result is slightly different on other devices. You can see in the image.

```
    let add = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "open"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeChords))
    add.tintColor = UIColor.black
    add.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -8)
    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add
```

[ss of simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNyRz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think its for the device sizes and the different icon sizes too.

In this link explain it, the different icon sizes and how it used by the device.

[iOS navigation bar item image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607674/ios-navigation-bar-item-image-size)

Another way, maybe this code help you

```
let customButton = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    customButton.setImage(UIImage.init(named:"imageName"), for: .normal)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: customButton)
```