# Navigation bar button images on swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

When trying to customize my navigation bar, it asks me about what images I want to use. I want to customize these images. I use Adobe illustrator to customize various icons. However, when I add the image to the assets and select it, the image is often larger than the navigation bar.

Comment: I guess you can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607674/ios-navigation-bar-item-image-size). The topic is similar.

Comment: Back button icon should be 24px size